# Fastest SQL Full Text Search

Tags: mysql, sqlite, full-text-search, benchmarking, fts3

I'm currently using SQLite FTS4 engine, and its performance is great. But does someone know of any benchmarks/comparison to MySQL's full text search (or any other SQL database)?

P.S. I'm not looking for any Lucene/NoSQL alternatives.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. Are you trying to compare a single-user, in-process, in-memory database with multi-user, server-based databases? How about SQLite's simplistic tokenizer/stemmer versus full feature stemming?

Comment: full text search??? you mean use `like '%abc%'`? remember that how the db config is set up is really important, the engine, index, etc."It's not the arrow, it's the Indian who make the difference"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Even though they have different target audiences, they would be both suitable for use in my desktop app (since you can use MySQL as a single-user in-process DLL too). And some timings how long it would take to find a certain word in a large dataset would be usefull for me, to see if it's worth making the switch.

Comment: @jcho360 LIKE-queries are not full-text search, but if you have benchmarks for them, I would be interested too.

Answer (score 5):

Bill Karwin from Percona performed benchmarks on Full-Text search MySQL vs Sphinx vs Lucene. You could find slides here http://bit.ly/M6DMsj

Comment: The link is dead. An archived version can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120907050341/http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/WEBINAR-full-text-search-throwdown.pdf)